# Azure Policy Multiple tags inside one policy assignment

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-policy

I want to create an automatically way to create a new policy that needs to apply default tags to every virtual machine that has been deployed.

At the moment i have the following

Powershell script:

```
#Remove Policy
#$scope = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName "subscriptionname"
#$SubscriptionID = "/subscriptions/" + $scope.Id
#Remove-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'apply-default-tag-1' -Scope $SubscriptionID




# Create the Policy Definition (Subscription scope)
$definition = New-AzPolicyDefinition -Name 'default-tags-to-vms' -DisplayName 'Append default tags to VM' -description 'This policy will add default tags to VMs' -Policy 'C:\policy.json' -Parameter 'C:\policy.parameters.json' -Mode All


# Set the scope to a resource group; may also be a resource, subscription, or management group
$scope = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName "DCS-EM-AZ1"
$SubscriptionID = "/subscriptions/" + $scope.Id



# Set the Policy Parameter (JSON format)
$Tag1 = '{ "tagName": { "value":  "Application"}, "tagValue": { "value":  "stackoverflow" } }'
$Tag2 = '{ "tagName": { "value":  "Contact"}, "tagValue": { "value":  "bekind" } }'
$Tag3 = '{ "tagName": { "value":  "Environment"}, "tagValue": {  "value": "tome" } }'
$Tag4 = '{ "tagName": { "value":  "RUNTIME"}, "tagValue": {  "value": "please" } }'




# Create the Policy Assignment
$policyTag1 = New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'apply-default-tag-1' -DisplayName 'Apply default tag Application ' -Scope $SubscriptionID -PolicyDefinition $definition -PolicyParameter $Tag1
$policyTag2 = New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'apply-default-tag-2' -DisplayName 'Apply default tag Contact '  -Scope $SubscriptionID -PolicyDefinition $definition -PolicyParameter $Tag2
$policyTag3 = New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'apply-default-tag-3' -DisplayName 'Apply default tag Environment '  -Scope $SubscriptionID -PolicyDefinition $definition -PolicyParameter $Tag3
$policyTag4 = New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'apply-default-tag-4' -DisplayName 'Apply default tag Runtime '  -Scope $SubscriptionID -PolicyDefinition $definition -PolicyParameter $Tag4
```

JSON files
policy.json

```
{
    "if": {
        "allOf": [{
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "exists": "false"
        },
        {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
        }
    ]
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "append",
        "details": [
            {
                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                "value": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

policy.parameters.json

```
{
    "tagName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the tag, such as costCenter"
        }
    },
    "tagValue": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Value of the tag, such as headquarter"
        }
    }
}
```

The above will deploy multiple azure policy asssignments with each assignment being a tagname and tagvalue and if I test the deployment inside the subscription than I can see that my policy works.
Ofcourse it's not only on the 'it works now' part. But also how can I make this efficient so that in the future can add this smooth without changing a lot of code.

What I've tried so far:

Instead of using powershell I've created the policy inside an ARM template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "tagName": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue":[  
                "default",
                "location",
                "is",
                "a",
                "problem"
            ]
        },
        "tagValue": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue":[  
                "hello",
                "darkness",
                "my",
                "old",
                "friend"
            ]
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
            "name": "[concat('append-tags-to-resource'parameters('tagName')[copyindex('CopyTags')])]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "properties": {
                "policyType": "Custom",
                "parameters": {},
                "policyRule": {
                    "if": {
                        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName')[copyindex('CopyTags')], ']')]",
                        "exists": "false"
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "effect": "append",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName')[copyindex('CopyTags')], ']')]",
                                "value": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "CopyTags",
                "count": "[length(parameters('tagName'))]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This gave me a lot of errors because I couldn't find a way to efficiently deploy this to a subscription as my scope instead of a resource group.
(I did tried to deploy this without providing a resource group but couldn't figure out where the deployment went, no errors , no policies in every subscription i am a user to)

Does anyone know a way to add multiple tags in an efficient way. (efficient: so that i can add more in the future without changing a lot by just adjusting the names and values inside an array). Or knows a better way to implement my policy powershell script ?